# Instagram login issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, instagram-api

I try to login by Instagram , and I refer [mbarwick83/instagram](https://github.com/mbarwick83/instagram).

When I try to login,it have some problem,only show some url：

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code
```

And go to url,have some message：

```
// 20171025142046
// https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code

{
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"
}
```

But I already setting "client_id" and "redirect_uri".

How can I fix this problem?Thanks.

---

Step by Step：

1.Install mbarwick83/instagram

`composer require mbarwick83/instagram`

2. Add something in config/app.php

`providers:Mbarwick83\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider::class`

`aliases:'Instagram'=> Mbarwick83\Instagram\Facades\Instagram::class`

3. Include 'Mbarwick83' in this project:

`use Mbarwick83\Instagram\Instagram;`

4.To publish the packages configuration file

`php artisan vendor:publish`

5.Add Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mbarwick83\Instagram\Instagram;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Mbarwick83Controller extends Controller
{

    public function index(Instagram $instagram)
    {
        return $instagram->getLoginUrl();
    }

    public function callback(Request $request, Instagram $instagram)
    {
        $response = $instagram->getAccessToken($request->code);
        // or $response = Instagram::getAccessToken($request->code);

        if (isset($response['code']) == 400)
        {
            throw new \Exception($response['error_message'], 400);
        }
       return $response['access_token'];
    }
}
```

6.Setting "client_id" and "redirect_uri":

Path: ../vendor/mbarwick83/instagram/src/config

```
<?php

return [

    'client_id'     => env('0264df467XXXXXX'),
    'client_secret' => env('6e5d9XXXXX4eeXX1'),
    'redirect_uri'  => env('http://localhost/login/Instagram/callback'),
    'scopes'        => 'basic public_content'

];
```

7.Setting ../routes/web.php

```
Route::get('login/Instagram', 'Mbarwick83Controller@index');
Route::get('login/Instagram/callback', 'Mbarwick83Controller@callback');
```

8.Setting ../.env

```
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID=0264df467XXXXXX
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET=6e5d9XXXXX4eeXX1
INSTAGRAM_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost/login/Instagram/callback
```

Comment: where is your env file?

Comment: @madalinivascu HI , at step 8.

Comment: @madalinivascu HI,and when I use public function index(Instagram $instagram)
{
    $data = $instagram->get('v1/users/self', ['access_token' => $access_token]);
    // $data = $instagram->get('v1/users/' $user-id, ['access_token' => $access_token]);
    return $data;
}

to get some problem，how can I fix it?

Comment: the acces_token is `$access_token  = $instagram->getAccessToken($request->code);`, you need to save the token in a db/session

Comment: @madalinivascu When I first time to login by Instagram, it doesn't have acces_token in database.

Comment: yes you need to get one using `$instagram->getAccessToken($request->code);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config file, remove the env function

```
return [

    'client_id'     => '0264df467XXXXXX',
    'client_secret' => '6e5d9XXXXX4eeXX1',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/login/Instagram/callback',
    'scopes'        => 'basic public_content'

];
```

Comment: HI: 
I Try to Change

<?php

return [
    'client_id'     => '0264df467XXXXXX',
    'client_secret' => '6e5d9XXXXX4eeXX1',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/login/Instagram/callback',
    'scopes'  => 'basic public_content'
];


And Have some problem :
// 20171025162839
// https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=0264df467958481d9550bb7313e5bd90&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code

{
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"
}

Comment: And Have Some Problem 

// 20171025162839
// https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=0264df467958481d9550bb7313e5bd90&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code

{
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"
}

Comment: you need to change the url in the instagram configuration page to be the same as your current url

Answer (score 1):

You're using `env()` wrong, it requires a key name, not the value. (Though you could set a "default value" as second parameter)

```
<?php
return [
    'client_id'     => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect_uri'  => env('INSTAGRAM_CALLBACK_URL'),
    'scopes'        => 'basic public_content'
];
```

`env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID')` will get the value of `INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID` from your `.env` file.